# Pointing EC2 instance via domain inside Route 53 with timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I've spent a lot of time looking for a solution, but this is a quite weird and tricky issue.

- I have AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu)
- I have a configured domain in AWS Route 53

Everything works properly via IP address of EC2 instance in web browser, but when I'm changing nginx.conf and adding server_name with my domain properties it's instantly throwing a timeout.

To be clear:

**Route 53:**

- added proper IP as A address
- added proper NS addresses
- checked everything via `dig` in terminal - it's okay.

**EC2 instance:**

- ubuntu instance
- node js app on port `8000`
- configured security group with `Outbound: All`, `Inbound: HTTP port 80 and Custom TCP Rule Port Range 8000`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mydomain.dev www.mydomain.dev;
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;

        root /home/ubuntu/mydomainfolder_dev/;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                #proxy_http_version 1.1;
                #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                #proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

after this `nginx.conf` change and restarting a service (`sudo service nginx restart`) makes a proper redirect of EC2 address to my domain, but there is a timeout... any ideas how to fix it guys?

also: `sudo netstat -tulpn` output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4581/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1608/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      935/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4581/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      935/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2486/node /home/ubu
```

**SOLUTION**
I guess I found something, checking `sudo nano /var/log/syslog` gives me weird DNS error:

```
Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

Comment: In your nginx configuration isn't `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;` redirecting your traffic to https/443 ?

Comment: It is a typo, firstly wanted to have a proper working domain without a https.

Answer (score 1):

Alter the security group to allow port 443 as well as port 80

You will need an SSL certificate on the nginx server also

Comment: I want to make working domain without SSL first, even `return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;` is returning a timeout.

Comment: I'm not the ngnix expert but $server_name could be replaced with www.mydomain.dev literal string

Comment: It doesn't matter because redirect work properly (ec2 instance -> domain), but still with timeout (reminder: without domain properties ec2 works properly).

Comment: From what you are saying, if nginx is correct, sounds like the domain name is not set up.

Comment: Yup, I'm thinking the same way, but in Route 53 I have proper `A` record as EC2 `IP` and DNS servers properly set up - so that's why looking an issue inside nginx...

Comment: Plus there are no errors inside `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, `nginx -t` passed and `nginx status` is active... I've no idea where to search for an issue.

Comment: Please ask a new question with all the details up to date.  I assume that your issue isn't resolved